# Estrutura de repetição de uma função

Tags: r

Olá! Estou com dificuldades para encontrar meu erro no programa abaixo. 
Eu quero gerar valores aleátorios de um vetor de níveis, contudo eu quero que a minha função retorne uma matriz de valores gerados. Meu programa esta retornando uma matriz, porém os valores das colunas são iguais.

Para um melhor entendimento: Tenho 4 níveis e quero gerar 10 valores para cada nivel. Meu intuito é fazer com que o programa retorne essa matriz de valores.

### Codigo do programa

```
 v = rep(0,4)

 for(k in 1:length(v)){


 rf = function(n,a,b,v)
   {

  u =runif(n,0,1) 

  x = (-log(u)) / (exp((b/v[k])-a))

  return(matrix(x,n,length(v))
   }

     }


  rf(10,-3,10,v=c(10,20,30,40))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso você não precisaria de loop também:

```
rf2 <- function(n, a, b, v) matrix(-log(runif(n, 0, 1)) / exp(b/rep(v, each = n)-a), 
                                   ncol = length(v))
```

Comparando com a solução do Rcoster:

```
set.seed(1)
m1 <- rf(10,-3,10,v=c(10,20,30,40))
set.seed(1)
m2 <- rf2(10,-3,10,v=c(10,20,30,40))
all.equal(m1, m2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Para atingir o resultado esperado, o `for()` deveria estar dentro da função - e não fora:

```
 rf <- function(n, a, b, v) {
  u <- runif(n, 0, 1) 
  out <- matrix(0, n, length(v))
  for (k in 1:length(v)) {
      out[, k] <- (-log(u)) / (exp((b/v[k])-a))
   }
   return(out)
}

rf(10,-3,10,v=c(10,20,30,40))
```

Só chamo atenção para a linha `u = runif(n, 0, 1)`, que dependendo do teu objetivo ela deve ir para dentro do `for()`.